# laravel form model binding through HTML syntax

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using blade template but i was to know that is there any way to use form binding on html syntax based form?. if i would do it in blade's way it would be like

`{{ Form::model( $user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'put' )) }}`

But what if i want to use it like we add a hidden field for `csrf_token()` like

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

Here is my HTML form code:

```
<form class="form-group" action="/update" method="post" id="EditCommunityForm">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="text" name="community_name" class="form-control">
</form>
```

**Edit:**

i would like to ask that is there a way to convert this syntax `{{ Form::model( $user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'put' )) }}` to plain HTML?

Comment: I dont quite understand the question, but you can add the hidden input for token like: {!! carf_field() !!} which will print out the <input type="hidden"... etc

Comment: i would like to ask that is there a way to convert this syntax `{{ Form::model( $user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'put' )) }}` to plain HTML? Thanks @Adam

Comment: If i understood right,  you dont have to worry about the csrf token. It will be rendered automatically when you call `{{ Form::close() }}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy. But this is not my question. i have updated question. Please read again thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do model binding directly into html. You'll have to fill your form "manually". And, in your case, we will have to do a trick to overwrite the browser default methods (post/get).

Heres an example:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.update', $user->id) }}" method="post">

    <!-- Overwrite post method as 'Put' -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>

    <!-- CSRF token -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Fills an input with a model value -->
    <input type="text" name="community_name" value="{{ $user->community_name }}"/>

</form>
```